# Use Django's ORM to find most recent message within each message thread

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I have a messaging feature much like Facebook's in that each person can send another person a message, creating a new message thread, and every following message between those two people will appear on the same thread. I created a 'messages' data table which stores all of the messages along with the thread_id, which looks something like this:

```
id    message    sender_id    receiver_id    thread_id    message_date
1     Hello Bob  3            5              1            ...
2     Hello Jon  5            3              1            ...
3     Hi Jane    2            4              2            ...
4     Hi Sara    4            2              2            ...
```

I want to use Django's ORM to return only the most recent message of each unique thread_id. How do I do this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
from django.db.models import Max
from myapp.models import Message
Message.objects.annotate(message_date=Max('message_date')).values('id__max')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Postgres, you can do `Message.objects.order_by('thread_id').distinct('thread_id')` Anything else, you could maybe do something like this:

```
#first, grab all Threads
threads = Thread.objects.all().prefetch_related('message_set')

# loop through the threads, and get the latest message
for thread in threads:
    latest_message = thread.message_set.latest('message_date')
```